# is there a way to switch an activity to android's default bluetooth activity

Tags: android

I wanted to ask if there is any way by which in the current activity we can switch to the system's default bluetooth activity just like those when we go to setting>Wireless and Network>Bluetooth Settings ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

You may also find the [Docs useful](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)

[Bluetooth Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

Comment: Can I consider it that by this way we can reduce our efforts to create our own bluetooth interface and just letting the program run smoothly without going into hectic coding?? Will the program return to the current activity when the work at the settings activity will be done??

Comment: It depends on what you mean and what you need. This will take you to the screen you ask for but you may still need to create a class to handle communication and so on. I have posted the link to the docs for bluetooth. There is also a Bluetooth Chat example in the sdk that can get you started if you need to send data back and forth

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept if it helped by clicking the checkmark so others can find it easier

Comment: hey codeMagic. I am posting a link to my another question. I am actually new to android so please help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344135/how-to-pass-commands-like-play-pause-to-remote-pc-running-a-media-player-connect

Comment: I looked but I'm not sure what you need to send for that without researching. But you can't parse a `String` to an `int` if it isn't actually a number. You will need to look into that to see what commands you need to send...sorry I couldn't be of more help

Comment: What I actually need to send is a basic command to the remote pc to play or pause the current running song on the media player, so that when I click a button (for which I have created a toggle button) like play/pause the song play or pauses on the computer.